# Another user granting access

Tags: python, authentication, flask, two-factor-authentication

I'm making an Flask app which requires that access is restricted if your are not at work and if you are at work access is granted by the shift manager.

It is a good practice to make two-factor authentification based on another user [user-role] granting you access?

If yes how would you implement it?

Comment: Is this question about authentication or about permission-checking?

Comment: It could be more about permission-checking. I don't what that to give access to app to personal that is missing that day.

Comment: Shift manager grants permission to a specific person or to some group of users?

Comment: To a specific user. Something like this: when a worker comes at work and wants to access the app fills the login form and a request is made to the shift manager. The shift manager accepts or not the login request.

Comment: sort of easy solution could be to implement something like flask-security, and have the shift manager to inactivate users who are not at work. That way, only active users can log in. Of course you need to set up the correct db User model and use something like flask-admin to make administration easy.